# How to keep custom text in Window (Win32)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, window

We can set window text with:

```
BOOL WINAPI SetWindowText(
  __in      HWND hWnd,
  __in_opt  LPCTSTR lpString
);
```

and this windows text by another application

```
int WINAPI GetWindowText(
  __in   HWND hWnd,
  __out  LPTSTR lpString,
  __in   int nMaxCount
);
```

I don't want to change my forms caption but I want to keep a custom text in window and get this text by another instance of same program. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way to do this is:

1. Define your own [WM_APP message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644930%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which instance A of your app will use to tell instance B's window "send me your private text".
2. When instance B receives this message, it can use [WM_COPYDATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649011%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to send a reply to instance A's window.
3. Instance A receives the data from WM_COPYDATA and does what it wants with it.

This scheme allows you to send arbitrary data (as long as it doesn't include pointers) provided that the data is reasonably small (say a few KB tops). It's also easy to implement. What it does lack is security controls, so if you have to prevent the bad guys from retrieving this data from your application you will need to use something more heavy-duty.

Comment: +1 the use of WM_COPYDATA, assuming the security issue is not an issue, is nice since it avoids the marshalling that I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but I think you will have to open the other process using `openProcess` and then use some function on the process handle to get the title text. Once you have the text, you can very well use that in your application. For getting the process if of the required process, you can use `EnumProcess`, here is a complete example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686701%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to define a windows message in the WM_APP range and send it from one instance to the other. You'd have to do your own marshalling though with something like GlobalAlloc.

Comment: Minor nitpick: `WM_USER` is for messages specific to a window class; `WM_APP` is for "application-wide" messages. Although of course you can use whatever you want without problems almost all of the time.

Comment: @Jon thanks for pointing that out, I wasn't familiar with the distinction, I've updated my answer.